# How to make this (github) source into a library/jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, github, intellij-idea

I would like to use this source: https://github.com/mongodb/casbah
How can I use this stuff? I would like to make a jar for a library. But I have no idea how. Tried it with Eclipse and IntelliJ. I downloaded the source with:

```
git clone git://github.com/mongodb/casbah
```

Now I have a casbah folder; I copied it to the project source (in Eclipse or IntelliJ) but I am not even able to compile it...there's always something like:

```
error: '{' expected but identifier found.
package casbah-dynamic.src.main.scala
```

Do I have to compile? How? And what after compiling? It's a Scala project, but I think that's not so important. As a Java project, I would have to do the same thing.

So what should I do?

---

Edit: I saw this stuff is existing (some parts of them) as a jar (http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/com/mongodb/). But I would like to use the source and learn how to use it.

Comment: Have you seen the stuff at [Setting up](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.1.5.0/setting_up.html)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Build it with [SBT](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki):

```
> git clone git://github.com/mongodb/casbah.git
> cd casbah
> sbt package
```

You'll get several jars:

```
> find ./ -iname "*.jar"
./casbah-query/target/scala-2.9.1/casbah-query_2.9.1-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
./casbah-core/target/scala-2.9.1/casbah-core_2.9.1-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
./casbah-util/target/scala-2.9.1/casbah-util_2.9.1-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
./target/scala-2.9.1/casbah_2.9.1-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
./casbah-commons/target/scala-2.9.1/casbah-commons_2.9.1-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
./casbah-gridfs/target/scala-2.9.1/casbah-gridfs_2.9.1-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```